# Auto-login to basic-auth-protected URLs from a Safari 5.1.x extension - possible?

Tags: authentication, safari, safari-extension, basic-authentication

I'm in charge of developing extensions (with the same set of functionality) for three browsers: Firefox, Chrome and Safari. One of the features is basic-auth auto-login. The credentials are fetched from our servers and then with a single click the user can login into a basic-auth-protected URL without the need to fill in the credentials manually.

I have it working for Firefox and Chrome. For Firefox, I take advantage of the fact that it caches the basic-auth credentials even if the request is done via XMLHttpRequest. So, I basically do this:

```
  //Make the basic-auth request to URL using XMLHttpRequest
  var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xml.open('GET', URL ,false, USERNAME , PASSWORD);
  xml.send('');
  //Now redirect the current tab to the URL
  window.content.document.location = URL;
```

This works fine for Firefox, and used to work fine for Chrome as well. Google changed a couple of stuff in the latest releases of Chrome, and I had to start using the onAuthRequest callback, which works fine (if not better, check this post for a reference: [Chrome plugin development: user:pass@url not supported by Google Chrome anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725654/chrome-plugin-development-userpassurl-not-supported-by-google-chrome-anymore)).

Now, the problem is with Safari 5.1. The XMLHttpRequest technique just doesn't seem to work, and I couldn't find an onAuthRequest equivalent. Does anyone know a way to achieve the same effect on Safari 5.1?

Comment: What if you set the `Authorization` header manually? E.g. `xml.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));`

Comment: Hi Wladimir. I've tried that as well, and while this specific request made with XMLHttpRequest authenticates, it just does not cache the credentials as it used to, and if I try accessing the same basic auth-protected URL in the browser afterwards, I get prompted for the credentials again. I think I've reacehd a dead end.

Comment: Sorry for reviving a dead topic but did you ever find solution for Safari?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while, I don't remember :( I also don't use MacOS anymore.